# How to call a variable from two separate tables

Tags: laravel

In my app, each user can create their own social 'group', similar to meetup.com. An example group might be "Let's play tennis on Thursday".

Users can see each group they've created from within their dashboard. I use the following code to display the groups they've created:

```
<a href="{{ route('groups.show',$group->id)}}">{{$group->group_title}}</a>
```

As you can see, this code shows the group title which is clickable and directs to their group page.

Now, each user also has a profile page, which has a little info about them. I show that info like this:

```
{{ Auth::user()->about_me }}
```

I want to show the groups that a user has created on their profile page. How would I do that?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<a href="{{ route('groups',$group->id)}}"> {{ Auth::user()->$group->group_title }} </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, but I think you are trying to display a list of the User's groups? If so, assuming you have setup your models correctly, you can do something like this in your `*.blade.php` file:

```html
@foreach(Auth::user()->groups as $group)
  <a href="{{ route('groups', $group->id)}}"> {{ $group->group_title }}</a>
@endforeach
```

If you are having trouble getting your model relationships setup, check out the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships) for help.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry my question wasn't clear, I've reworded it now. Hope it's clearer.